# Multiple textareas per row in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

I have a small website where the user can input some text and this text is then processed in different ways, for example all chars are converted to uppercase/lowercase and other useful gimmicks. The results are shown in multiple textarea-blocks. I want the website to be usable on mobile devices so I use Bootstrap.
Normally each textarea gets it's own row, but I want to group some of them by  placing two or three next to each other.

My code (for two textareas) currently looks like the following:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                <textarea
                    id="textarea1"
                    class="form-control"
                ></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <textarea
                    id="textarea2"
                    class="form-control"
                ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbh69otv/)**

This kinda works and looks as expected, but as soon as the user tries to resize the textarea, the left textarea gets behind the right one, like [image: in the following picture]:

I believe this happens because of Bootstraps grid-system.

Is there any way to have the textareas 'push' each other and have a responsive design at the same time?

Comment: if you want, we can restrict that particular textarea within that container itself, so that i wont go behind the right textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use **resize** property like

```
textarea { resize: vertical; }
```

It only moves textarea **down**.  See **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbh69otv/embedded/result/)**

Comment: @Dennis, it glad for me... All the best

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable the resize option from texrare using CSS. Just apply the resize none style as follows:-

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
    max-width:100%;

}
```

Comment: Mh, I will think about that. But what if I want to keep the ability to resize the textarea? Maybe I should put both textareas in one column with the size of two columns (col-md-8)

Comment: If you want to keep it realizable then apply the following style.

textarea{max-width:100%;}

Answer (score 0):

if you add the css `float:right` to your class `form-control` it should stop overlapping.